# Filter lightning:datatable with select-picklist and multiple apex classes

Tags: datatable, salesforce, apex

i try to filter datatable results by clicking a lightning:select value. If I have the value "Alle" it should show all values and filter the datatable when clicking any other value. Do you have an idea how to adjust the js controller and the helper so it works? I already tried it by using Case but it isnt supported in the developer console. I made a second apex class to contain all values and the other one which is for the values when a picklist value is selected

```
public class MediathekSearchController {

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<List<sObject>> getSearchResult(String searchKey, String KategorieValue){
     String findStr = '*'+searchKey+'*';
     Boolean isEmptySearch = String.isEmpty(searchKey);
    
         List<List<sObject>> searchResult = [FIND : findStr
                                            IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING
                                            Mediathek__c (Id, Name, Bezeichnung__c, Typ__c, Zielgruppe__c, Umfang__c, Bezeichnung_Link__c, Bezeichnung_Search__c)];
        return searchResult; 
        }
    
        
    public static List<List<sObject>> getFilteredSearchResult(String searchKey, String KategorieValue){        
     String findStr = '*'+searchKey+'*';
     Boolean isEmptySearch = String.isEmpty(searchKey);
        
         List<List<sObject>> searchResultFiltered = [FIND : findStr
                                                    IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING
                                                    Mediathek__c (Id, Name, Bezeichnung__c, Typ__c, Zielgruppe__c, Umfang__c, Bezeichnung_Link__c, Bezeichnung_Search__c WHERE Typ__c=:KategorieValue)];
        return searchResultFiltered; 
        }
}
```

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="MediathekSearchController">

<!-- handlers-->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>

<!-- attributes -->
<aura:attribute name="showSearchResults" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKey" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="mediathekList" type="List" default="Mediathek[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="mediathekColumns" type="List"/>
 <aura:attribute name="KategorieValue" type="String" default="Alle"/>


<div class= "slds-box">
    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >
        <div class="slds-size_12-of-12">
    <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
        <lightning:layoutItem  size="8">
            <lightning:input name="searchKey" placeholder="Suchbegriff einfügen" value="{!v.searchKey}"  onkeydown="{!c.search}"/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem  size="2">
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Suchen" title="Search" onclick="{!c.search}" class="customButton" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem  size="2">
         <lightning:select aura:id="KategorieValue" name="Kategorie" label="Kategorie" required="false" value="{!v.KategorieValue}">
                  
        <option value="Alle">Alle</option>
        <option value="Formular">Formular</option>
        <option value="Merkblatt">Merkblatt</option>
        <option value="Flyer">Flyer</option>
        <option value="Infobroschüre">Infobroschüre</option>
        </lightning:select>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</div>
</div>
<div class="haha">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSearchResults}">
 
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12" >
                <lightning:datatable keyField="id"
                                     data="{!v.mediathekList}"
                                     columns="{!v.mediathekColumns}"
                                     hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
                
                
    
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </aura:if>
</div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

JS Controller

```
({
init: function (component, event, helper){
   component.set('v.mediathekColumns', [
        {label: 'Bezeichnung', fieldName: 'Bezeichnung_Search__c', type: 'url' , fixedWidth: 395, 
         typeAttributes: {label: { fieldName: 'Bezeichnung__c' }, target: '_blank'}
        },
       {label: 'Typ', fieldName: 'Typ__c', type: 'text',  fixedWidth: 116,
        },
       {label: 'Zielgruppe', fieldName: 'Zielgruppe__c', type: 'text', fixedWidth: 116,
        },
       {label: 'Umfang', fieldName: 'Umfang__c', type: 'text', fixedWidth: 112,
       },
       
     
      ]);
         var action = component.get("c.getSearchResult");
   
    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            var records =response.getReturnValue();
            records.forEach(function(record){
                
                record.BEZ = record.Bezeichnung__c;
            });
            component.set("v.mediathekList", records);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},




    
search : function(component, event, helper) {
    helper.getSearchResultsFromApex(component, event, helper);
    component.set("v.showSearchResults",true);
} })
```

Helper

```
    ({
    getSearchResultsFromApex : function(component, event, helper){
     
        var action = component.get("c.getSearchResult");
        
       
        action.setParams({ searchKey : searchStr, KategorieValue :  kategoryVal});
        // Create a callback that is executed after
        // the server-side action returns
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
 var result = response.getReturnValue();
  result.forEach(function(result){
                    result.Name = '/'+result.Id;
                    
                });
               
                // SOSL will always return the list in the order they were queried
                component.set("v.mediathekList",result[0]);
                  
                
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
                else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    var errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors) {
                        if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                            console.log("Error message: " +
                                        errors[0].message);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unknown error");
                    }
                }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is to be honest?

```apex
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<List<sObject>> getSearchResult(String searchKey, String KategorieValue){
    String findStr = '*'+searchKey+'*';
    List<List<sObject>> searchResult;

    if(String.isBlank(kategorieValue)) || kategorieValue == 'Alle'){
        searchResult = [FIND :findStr IN ALL FIELDS 
            RETURNING Mediathek__c (Id, Name, Bezeichnung__c, Typ__c, Zielgruppe__c, Umfang__c, Bezeichnung_Link__c, Bezeichnung_Search__c)];
    } else {
        searchResult = [FIND :findStr IN ALL FIELDS 
            RETURNING Mediathek__c (Id, Name, Bezeichnung__c, Typ__c, Zielgruppe__c, Umfang__c, Bezeichnung_Link__c, Bezeichnung_Search__c
            WHERE Typ__c=:KategorieValue)];
    }

    return searchResult;
}
```

If you feel really fancy you could look into dynamic soql or maybe using real data categories for it (more than just a picklist) but plain old `if` should be enough?